# Where (on the internet) should I ask for a broad question?

Tags: discussion

I'm already aware that StackExchange websites are not for advices/recommendations/broad questions and I enjoy this as a Stackoverflow user. However, as a complete ignorant toward biology I would like to get general advices about a field of biology.

Where can I do that ? Is SE suggesting websites to do so ?

Comment: Quora is a good place if you are looking for advice but you definitely need to ping competent people through Ask to answer. Finding them is a difficult task because top answerers are not the specialists of the field there, you will find a writer (I don't remember correctly, he was probably a career-consultant) among the top answerers of Genetics. 
Also try reddit. It is pretty good and has subreddits for many branches of biology.

Answer (score 1):

Biology is a huge field. There are forums on specific biology topics. I haven't used/checked out forums other than those on bioinformatics. You can use our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1997/the-biosphere) for discussions about biology. Discussions are not allowed on the main site because the crux generally gets lost. SE does not have any specific recommendations.